# Add dynamic class in content box in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I am working on OpenCart 1.5.6.4. I want to add dynamic CSS class in content box. I want the following options for the content box layout:

- left panel + main content + right panel
- only left panel + main content
- only main content + right panel
- only main content (without left & right panels)

With the following code each case **except the main content + right panel** is working:

```
 <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>">.....</div>
```

I get this results:
[image]

What is wrong here with the last option? How can I fix it?

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: When you have only the __right__ column and it should be `col-sm-9` + `col-sm-3` please check (print out) the `$column_left` - obviously it is not empty (it may contain some empty `<div>` for example) or even check the `catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/common/column_left.tpl` template...

Comment: Here, not issue in right & left column. but, I want to add class col-sm-9 in main content when layout only main content + right panel. but, Here, I get class col-sm-6 in main content.

Comment: I know what is the problem and therefore I am asking you to check the `$column_left` variable (or it's template) when only column right + main content should be there...

Comment: Thank You so much. solved issue. It was space issue add of code in `$column_left` file.

Comment: OK, will write an answer for this so that You can accept it.

Comment: @shadyyx Hi, if, i have use this code in latest module(latest.tpl). So, It is not working. any idea? It is working fine in category page(category.tpl). Thanks.

Comment: Why did you delete your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks completely fine and should be working. The reason it seems it is not is because most probably you have some data in the `$column_left` even if it should be empty (thus considered as `false`).

The best bet is to either check the `$column_left` variable when there should be only main content + right column displayed (`print_r($column_left)`) or check the left column's template immediately (`catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/common/column_left.tpl`).

Normally the code in `column_left.tpl` should be

```
<?php if ($modules) { ?>
<div class="column_left">
    <?php /* ... */ ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

It is possible that You have something like this instead:

```
<div class="column_left">
<?php if ($modules) { ?>
    <?php /* ... */ ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

therefore there is empty `<div>` and your code correctly uses `col-sm-6` for main content.

After fixing the `column_left.tpl` you should have `col-sm-9` for main content + `col-sm-3` for right column if there is no left column data.